# Rails: Rspec user index admin user not included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Factory user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username "Matin"
    password "123456"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end
end
```

`user_controller_spec.rb`

```
before :each do
  session[:user_id] = create(:admin).id
end

describe "user access to orders" do

  describe "GET#index" do
    it " populates an array of all users" do
      smith = create(:user,username:'smith')
      jones = create(:user,username:'jones')
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:users)).to match_array([smith, jones])
    end
    it "render the :index template" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end
  end
```

This can not pass test and show error

> expected collection contained:[User id: 2, username: "smith"] 
>  actual
>   collection contained: [User id: 1, username: "Matin"] 
> the extra
>   elements were:      [User id: 1, username: "Matin"]

I think error happens because I did not put admin user into `match_array`. 
How to add admin user into `match_array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save admin user to variable and then use it:

```
before :each do
  @admin = create(:admin)
  session[:user_id] = @admin.id
end

...

    get :index
    expect(assigns(:users)).to match_array([@admin, smith, jones])
```